# Do dragons respawn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've found one as per the story, and I found another simply named dragon.

Do they respawn? Can I kill an endless amount of dragons therefore filling the land with skeletons or is there a fixed number?

Comment: one did re-spawn on me. I killed the dragon near magic collage. later when I came back there the bones were gone and a dragon attacked me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Game Director Todd Howard, [there are an unlimited number of dragons.](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/05/18/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-to-have-an-unlimited-number-of-dragons/)

Comment: That may be the most beautiful sentence I've ever read.

Comment: What, really?! Oh my god. I love this game.