# How many dragons are there in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'd like to know if there is a specific amount of dragons in the game or if they are "generated" randomly? There are "main dragons" and "simple dragons" (dragons that can be killed like simple monsters) in the game story?

Comment: number of dragons are infinite, but they are all scaled to your level

Comment: [According to Game Director Todd Howard, there are an unlimited number of dragons.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35551/12936)

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate. The answers happen to be similar, but the questions are asking two different things (the OPs most likely had different goals in mind when they asked the questions).

Comment: @Zignd This question has been closed (preventing it from getting further answers), but I have voted to reopen it (needs four more votes to reopen). If this doesn't get reopened after a day or two, and you would like it to be reopened, you could raise this issue at [meta].

Comment: @galacticninja So if this doesn't work I can go to the Meta and ask for votes theres? How should I do that? If you could explain me what is this "raise this issue" I'd appreciate. Also thanks for the reopen vote :)

Comment: @Zign Check out the existing posts like that in [meta] to have an idea: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen?sort=votes&pagesize=15

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are an infinite numbers of dragons in Skyrim, [since most of them respawn](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Lairs), like other creatures.

The number of *named* "main" dragons are fixed though, though and they are listed in the [UESP wiki "Dragon" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon#Named_Dragons). There are more info regarding dragons at the same UESP wiki article.

Comment: This is kind of a spoiler comment. The link in the answer was enough for a player to decide if he/she wants to know it or not.

Comment: @JarrodMosen, that should be `"Spoiler alert:"` not `"For the lazy:"`.=)

Answer (score 1):

They are randomly generated, there is no specific amount in game,